# problem with an abstract type as class member variable

Tags: c++, class, virtual

I try to use a abstract class type as a member variable in my class definition, but somehow it has some problem. Here is the abstract class type:

```
class POINT{
   public:
       virtual int point_dim() = 0;
       /*other virtual functions...*/ 
}
```

And here is the inherited class:

```
class POINTX : public POINT{
   public:
       int point_dim(){return 10;}
}
```

I create another class to use POINT as a member variable, since POINT is a pure virtual class, I can only declare it as a pointer:

```
class SPACE{
   public:
       POINT* m_point;
       /*some other declarations*/
}
```

But when I use it in my main, it does not work as I expect:

```
int main(){
    POINTX *ptx = new POINTX();
    SPACE space;
    space.m_point = (POINT*)ptx;
    //some function call use POINT as parameter(pass by reference):
    func(*space.m_point, ....);
}
```

error happened when func(space.m_pint) is invoked. However, if I do this without class SPACE, it's ok. e.g.:

```
int main(){
    POINTX *ptx = new POINTX();
    POINT *m_point = (POINT*)ptx;
    //some function call use POINT as parameter(pass by reference):
    func(*m_point, ....);
}
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: POINTX class is missing const. The casts are not needed. The func() should take a reference as parameter.

Comment: General advice for any question: how does it not work?  What happens, and how does it differ from what you expect to happen?  Specific advice for this question: what is the definition of `func`?  It might make a difference what the first argument to `func` actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POINT` declares:

```
   virtual int point_dim() const = 0;
```

Therefore `POINTX` must have a `const` method called `point_dim`:

```
   int point_dim() const {return 10;}
```

Without this, it will have two `point_dim()` methods, one non-`const` and one `const` but pure `virtual`, leaving `POINTX` as abstract.

As long as `func()` takes a *reference* to a `POINT`:

```
int func(const POINT& pt)
{
    const int dim = pt.point_dim();
    // ...
}
```

You'll be able to call it like this:

```
func(*space.m_point);
```

Also, note that you don't need the C-style cast here:

```
space.m_point = ptx;
```

And don't forget to `delete ptx` when you're done!

Comment: In that case, would the `new POINTX` line compile?

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: I wouldn't have thought so. I suspect that is what is mant by the very ambiguous "but somehow it has some problem."

Comment: @Johnsyweb, thanks for ur answer. The const is a mistake, sorry about that. Actually the func() is a member function within another class, but I guess it doesn't make any difference as long as it takes a reference. But func(*space.m_point) got segmentation fault error when its being called... And func(*m_point) work properly, I dont understand that!

Comment: @hsienting: We can't help without real code or a proper description of the problem. "`func(*m_point)` work properly" is not a description of a problem.

Comment: @hsienting: The fact that `func` is a member function of another class is unlikely to change anything. http://ideone.com/TgiEK demonstrates that this code can work and return `10`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, hmm... let me dig it deeper and post later. Thanks for clearing things for me.